# Где можно использовать шорткоды в Вордпресс?

Tags: wordpress, плагин

В данной статье

```
http://wpcreate.ru/rasshirenie-funktsionala-sayta/shortkodyi-v-wordpress.html
```

говорят что
Шорткод — это такая произвольная, пользовательская функция, которую можно вызывать в **записях и статьях** на своем сайте, используя короткое имя.

что действительно только в записях?

ведь например плагин Hude it с помощью шорткода вставляется на странице.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> что действительно только в записях?

Нет, не действительно. Можно вставлять в текстовый редактор любого типа записи. Можно вставлять в даже в виджеты если включить поддержку (отдельный плагин или функция в теме). Можно вставлять и в код с пом функции [do_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)

См оф документацию https://codex.wordpress.org/ru:Shortcode_API